# Set button function as back key

Tags: android, button, back

I'm creating a menu that I want to be in all of my activities. For this, I'm creating a class with all buttons definitions and onClickListeners.

The problem that I encountered is when defining the back button to act as the physical back button. The way I created this class, it doesn't recognize the `finish()`, `onBackPressed()` etc.. functions. So, what will be the way to do it this way??

```
public class MenuView extends RelativeLayout {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;


public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(goBack);
}


private final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //HERE TO INSERT THE WAY TO DO IT
    }
};
```

Comment: Your answer is correct to, you'r right, but the one accepted is more detailed, so it was easier to understand for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a context is a member variable and assign it in your constructor like this:

```
Context context;

public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(goBack);
  }
```

and in your click listener you can add this line of code:

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Try it. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 4):

Should be enough to extract `context` attribute as a member variable and use it in the listener like `((Activity) context).finish()`.

Answer (score 1):

To finish the current visible `Activity` , you will need the reference of it.

Give it a try,

```
    public class MenuView extends RelativeLayout {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity mActivity;

public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mActivity = (Activity)context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(goBack);
}


private final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    mActivity.finish();
    }
};
```

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: Tryed this but when inflating the class to inster into the layout I get  the following `the following classes could not be instantiated` and it refers to the line where I define the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this, onBackPressed() just call this method it will work

```
 private final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //HERE TO INSERT THE WAY TO DO IT

onBackPressed();
}
};
```

Comment: ´The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type new View.onClickListener()´.